# Contact form will not Send off unless all Fields are filled, Need Field to be Optional?

Tags: php

This is the code for my contact form, its pretty short, the site uses java and php, if that matters to mention. Anyways, "Email" and "Name" fields need to be optional, but it will not send unless they are filled, what needs to be changed down below?  (Im not a good php guy, so example or copying it in your answer will help) thanks!

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$from = 'NewFeedBack@ReviewBM.com';
$to = 'Mike@gmail.com';
if ($_POST['sender_subject'] and $_POST['sender_message'] and $_POST['sender_name'] and $_POST['sender_email']) {
    $message = "Complainers email: " . $_POST['sender_email'] . "\r\nComplainers name: " . $_POST['sender_name'] . "\r\nComplainers message: " . $_POST['sender_message'] . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From:" . $from;
    mail($to, $_POST['sender_subject'], $message, $headers);
    $data = array('status'=>0);
    echo(json_encode($data));
}else{
    $data = array('status'=>1);
    echo(json_encode($data));
}
return;
```

Comment: `if($_POST['sender_subject'] && $_POST['sender_message']){` just remove them. Or `if(!empty($_POST['sender_subject']) && !empty($_POST['sender_message'])){`

Comment: Haha, I know it was something simple, but I dont know coding at all.   I used the first option you listed, just removed them. Hopefully that is just as good. Thanks dude! Simple save made my day.

Comment: You're welcome. I wasn't sure if you had seen my comment or not, so I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just remove `and $_POST['sender_name'] and $_POST['sender_email']`

and do:

```
if($_POST['sender_subject'] && $_POST['sender_message']){
```

Or, you can also use:

```
if(!empty($_POST['sender_subject']) && !empty($_POST['sender_message'])){
```

`!empty()` checks if the fields were not empty.

---

Sidenote: `&&` has precedence over `AND`, just a quick FYI.